# jpa mapping java type to database type

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdbc

Every JPA-Provider (at least hibernate, eclipselink and openjpa) gives the possibility to create the ddl-schema on the basis of the jpa entity classes. But every database management system has his own data types.

So how do the jpa-providers decide which sql datatype will be chosen. (I think it will be provider specific). Is there a Mapping like `String->varchar(xx), boolean->tinyint` and so on. But then this mapping has to be exist for every database, right?  Can anyone put me in the right direction please? I searched in the hibernate source-code but I did not find the right code snippets.

Thanks!

Comment: Look the source code of MySQLDialect class for hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then this mapping has to be exist for every database, right?

You are right. The same is specified in the Dialect which is being used in DB connections.

For whatever I have searched this **information is encapsulated inside the dialect** driver for the DB which you use and the same must contain the mapping of `java types -> db types`.

[Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.0.SP1/org/hibernate/dialect/Oracle9Dialect.java#Oracle9Dialect) you can see mapping in **Constructor**.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects) class and implementations thereof.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

For each DBMS hibernate maintains dialect. which is available in hibernateX.jar.